# VS 2010 SP1 and SQL CE - Does it support foreign keys?

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

If ever asked what I like most about EF4 when used with Sql Server 2008 then I would reply that it picks up foreign keys on my database schemas. Is this the case for VS 2010 SP1 and SQL CE? I don't want to spend hours upfront to find out SQL CE does not work like that. So, I'm asking anyone who has experienced this scenario.

Comment: Foreign keys are a fundamental part of relational database design. It is inconceivable that SQL Server CE would not support them.

Comment: Does EF4 pick up these foreign keys on SQL Server CE? You've tried this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, EF 4 works very well with SQL CE, including picking up foreign keys. You can download and examine a sample project from here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html